# SQL stored procedure to change the queried data table to the latest year's

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to run various blocks of code that perform different tasks (SQL functions) on a data table that gets created each year with new data. So I have a newly-created data table named "Table2023"; and a collection of previous years' tables "Table2022", "Table2021" etc

I am trying to write a stored procedure that can quickly update all the lines of SQL code in a block of code that point to "Table2022", so that they now point to "Table2023".

Basically, so I can repeat everything I did last year, but for the latest 2023 year's data.

Before I became aware of stored procedures, I previously used to highlight the blocks of code and use the Find and Replace function to find "Table2022" and replace it with "Table2023", and then run the updated block of code. However, having read a little about Stored Procedures, that seems a better way. Particularly as I now have lengthy blocks of code.
I have looked at other examples about dynamics using DECLARE and SET, but they look more complicated and have struggled to try adapt that (more complicated) code for what I need to do here which is more simplistic, but beyond my basic grasp of SQL

But for illustrative purposes here, I've just shown a very basic distinct count block of code as an example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcedure1] 
    @TableYYYY nvarchar(50)
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(1) AS 'NumberOfRecords'
    FROM '@TableYYYY'

-- And then to execute the StoredProcedure1,
EXEC [dbo].[StoredProcedure1] @TableYYYY = [raw].Table2023
```

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Please tag your question properly.  It is useless if someone post a solution, but it's for the wrong vendor because you can't use it.

Comment: This is a really bad design, why isn't it all in one table with a `Date` column?